# Perl regular expression example not working

Tags: perl

I am just trying to test something I have seen in a magazine (Linux Shell Handbook).  I have never really tried anything like this, but I know this could be useful

The example is

```
perl -n -e '/^The \s+(.*)$/ print "$1\n"' heroes.txt
```

In heroes.txt it has

```
Catwoman
Batman
The Tick
Spider-Man
Black Cat
Batgirl
Danger Girl
Wonder Woman
Luke Cage
Ant-Man
Spider-Woman
```

And this should display Tick, however I am getting

```
perl -n -e '/^The \s+(.*)$/ print "$1\n"' heroes.txt
syntax error at -e line 1, near "/^The \s+(.*)$/ print"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: need semicolon before the print

Comment: No, need an if statement [like in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662424/465183)

Comment: Thanks that works, but how can I show just one line

Comment: @geekcomputers see sputnick's response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better do this :

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /^The\s+(.*)$/' heroes.txt
Tick
```

or

```
$ perl -lne '/^The\s+(.*)$/ && print $1' heroes.txt
Tick
```

You have some mistakes in your original command :

```
perl -n -e '/^The \s+(.*)$/ print "$1\n"' heroes.txt
```

- this is a syntax error, you can't use `m//` (*match* operator, the `m` is not mandatory if used with `/` delimiter) followed by `print` :
- better use an `if` or `&&` (like in my 2 snippets) statement to not printing not matching lines
- `\s` is already a space (or blank characters), so don't repeat both a literal space  and `\s`

---

```
action if condition;
```

is a shorthand for

```
if (condition) {action};
```

Comment: Can I be cheeky and ask you to look at this example as well perl -n -e '/^(\w+)-(\w+)$/ print "$1 $2\n"' heroes.txt

Comment: Yes I have I am just trying to get my head round it, thanks very much for your help

Comment: @geekcomputers if you really want to place the regular expression before the print statement, place `&&` before the print: `perl -n -e '/^(\w+)-(\w+)$/ && print "$1 $2\n"' heroes.txt`